# post mapping rest api spring boot cannot get id

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Im learning, and so far i created many to many bidirectional database - user can create many groups and group can have many users -  and i cannot find a way for my GroupsController Post mapping to work, from my understanding, it requires to get firstly Users id, in order to set the right relationship in Join table for Group, because the relationship should be set only when user create/join group, not when user create sign up procedure. Postman throws 500 and intelliJ:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Long.longValue()" because the return value of "com.ilze.highlight.entity.Groups.getId()" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Long.longValue()" because the return value of "com.ilze.highlight.entity.Groups.getId()" is null
```

I use lombok - @Data, @Getter, therefore getId() should be available for use from Group class. My GroupsController with POST mapping when user decides to create a new group:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/groups") // pre-path
public class GroupsController{


  @Autowired
  private GroupsService groupsService;

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  private final GroupsRepository groupsRepository;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  public GroupsController(GroupsRepository groupsRepository) {
    this.groupsRepository = groupsRepository;
  }

  @GetMapping("/all-groups")
  public List<Groups> getGroups(){
    return (List<Groups>) groupsRepository.findAll();
  }

  @PostMapping("/user/{usersId}/create-group")
  public ResponseEntity<Groups> createGroup(@PathVariable(value = "usersId") Long usersId, @RequestBody Groups groupRequest){
    Groups group = userRepository.findById(usersId).map(users -> {
      long groupsId = groupRequest.getId();

      // add and create new group
      users.addGroup(groupRequest);
      return groupsRepository.save(groupRequest);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Not found user with id = " + usersId));

    return new ResponseEntity<>(group, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

Group database class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Table(name = "group_collection")
public class Groups {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name ="group_name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
  private String groupName;

  @Column(name = "size", nullable = false)
  private int size;

  @Column(name = "strict", nullable = false)
  private boolean strict;

  @Column(name = "open", nullable = false)
  private boolean open;

  @Column(name ="description", length = 300)
  private String description;

  @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false)
  private LocalDateTime createTime;


  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
  cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE,
    CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.REFRESH
  },
  mappedBy = "groups")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();


  public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
  }

  public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
  }

}
```

And Users class for database:

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false)
  private LocalDateTime createTime;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
  private Role role;

  @Transient
  private String accessToken;

  @Transient
  private String refreshToken;


  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade = {
      CascadeType.PERSIST,
      CascadeType.MERGE,
      CascadeType.DETACH,
      CascadeType.REFRESH
    })
  @JoinTable(name = "groups_x_user",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "users_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "groups_id")})
  private Set<Groups> groups = new HashSet<>();


  public void addGroup(Groups group) {
    this.groups.add(group);
    group.getUsers().add(this);
  }

  public void removeGroup(long id){
    Groups group = this.groups.stream().filter(g ->
      g.getId() == id).findFirst().orElse(null);
    if(group != null){
      this.groups.remove(group);
      group.getUsers().remove(this);
    }
  }
```

For reference my GroupsService implementation:

```
@Service
public class GroupsServiceImpl implements GroupsService{

  private final GroupsRepository groupsRepository;

  public GroupsServiceImpl(GroupsRepository groupsRepository) {
    this.groupsRepository = groupsRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public Groups saveGroup(Groups group) {
    group.setCreateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    return groupsRepository.save(group);
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Groups> findByGroupName(String groupName) {
    return groupsRepository.findByGroupName(groupName);
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to access `usersId`? `groupRequest.getId()` would come from the request body. What does the request body look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the object from request. And since you have Many-2-Many relation, you can insert related object from both sides. In your case: just add existing user to the newly created group

The method will look something like that:

```java
@PostMapping("/user/{usersId}/groups")
public ResponseEntity<Groups> createGroup(@PathVariable(value = "usersId") Long usersId, @RequestBody Groups groupRequest) {
     Groups createdGroup = userRepository.findById(usersId)
     .map(user -> {
          groupRequest.setId(null); // ID for new entry will be generated by entity framework, prevent override from outside
          groupRequest.getUsers().add(user); // add relation
          return groupsRepository.save(groupRequest);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Not found user with id = " + usersId));

    return new ResponseEntity<>(createdGroup, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```